# Laravel Validation Rule - At least one input value change must be made

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a model with title, subtitle, date and am building a form that will allow a user to submit a change request.

How can I validate to ensure at least one edit is made comparing the input fields to database values?

I think the below would ensure the title entered is different from the value in 'different:', but how would I only do this for at least one field?

```
public function rules()
{

    return [
        'title' => [
            'required',
            'different:Dynamic Title name here',
            'string',
            'max:60',
            'not_regex:/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u'
        ],
        'subtitle' => [
            'string',
            'nullable',
            'max:90',
            'not_regex:/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u'
        ]

    ];

}
```

e.g. 
Title, Subtitle, Date fields are shown. A user must edit at least one of them from the current set database values in order to submit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your solution, but I'd recommend to take a look at isDirty() function.

```
/**
* this will return false, because after we get the record from
* database, there's no attribute of it that we changed. we just 
* print if it's dirty or not. so it tells us: "I'm clean, nobody has 
* changed my attributes at all.
*/
$role = Role::findOrFail(1);
return $role->isDirty();

/**
* lets say We fetched this role with id=1 and its status was 1. what
* this returns is still false, because even though we set the status
* attribute equal to 1, we still didn't change it. It was 1 when we
* received it from the database and it's still 1.
*/
$role = Role::findOrFail(1);
$role->status = 1;
return $role->isDirty();

/**
* now if the status was 1 in the db, and we set it to 2, it will 
* print the true.
*/
$role = Role::findOrFail(1);
$role->status = 2;
return $role->isDirty();
```

You can also pass an argument to `isDirty()` function which will only check that specific column value.

Comment: Thanks Giorgi - that could be useful - just doing some trial and error with it now but what I have done doesn't seem like the 'laravel way' and is quite verbose. Hoping for a native solution

Comment: use isDirty() then, it's the laravel way and quite flexible. read more . but basically What I posted as an answer could be all you need.

Comment: Thanks - I am trying to use it as part of the validation rules function. So retrieving the existing model, comparing it to the data all working fine, but then it's how to return that as a broken validation rule if it's dirty. Any idea?

Comment: @FriendlyCode Regarding to your question. Validation rules are meant to ensure the given data comply with our specifications. In this case this is a logical validation (business), so I think this logic should be put in the controller, or even better, in a middleware, after passing the validation.

Comment: I agree with @HCK. use my solution and put it in a middleware or controller. what you're asking is not validation logic which laravel provides as rules.

Comment: @FriendlyCode about how to return a message when your validation rule isn't passed. You can check [this](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/custom-validation-rules-in-laravel-5-5-c6cb250f65df) (or see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsKOhgflCmI)) to know how to write your [custom validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules). Hope this helps, have a nice day.

Comment: @FriendlyCode also, as an advice, this kind of validation can also be delegated to the front-end. To avoid hitting the database.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I have it all working as required. It does need to hit the db as when the revision request is made the values need to be checked at that point in time :)